# Не получается сохранить введенный текст в input с помощью localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

я работаю с localStorage впервые, так как ещё изучаю JavaScript и зная отлько азы, не могу понять как сделать следущее: При вводе текста в input, а затем после нажатия кнопки сохранить/save, текст выводится в див по имени result, но как с помощью localStorage сделать так, что бы он сохранился, что бы при попытке перезагрузить или выйти из страницы, он не исчезал из дива!? Я перепробовала многие варианты в которых была уверена, а так же в интенете но результаты были не те. 
Буду очень благодарна если кто-то поможет.

```
<body>


 <input type="text" class="text"/><button onclick="save()">Save</button>
 <div id="result"></div>
```

```
#result{
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```
<script>

function save(){

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].value;
var b = document.getElementById("result");
b.innerHTML = a;
```

}

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в Вашем коде слова `localStorage`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, дело было в том, что я не знала как его правильно написать, потому что, то что писала я, всегда выводило ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт должен быть после `<div id="result"></div>`.

```
function save() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].value;
  var b = document.getElementById("result");
  b.innerHTML = a;

  localStorage.setItem("myText", a);
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("myText");
```

Comment: Благодарю, я перепробовала множество тяжёлых и запутанных вариантов со скриптами, а оказалось, нужно было сохранить и извлечь его обычным способом.

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk На здоровье. Успехов!